# clustering k-means are not spherical

Tags: machine-learning, k-means, unsupervised-learning

I'm a beginner in data science and I need your help
I'm trying to test unsupervised machine learning with the K-means
but I found that the result is not spherical. I normalized, I removed the outliers etc. 
I tried to find several way to correct it but it doesn't work

Here are pictures:
(I took a little sample of the dataset to show you, it's actually 8000 rows)

[image] ... 
[image]

Comment: What are you plotting? what are x-axis and y-axis?. Provide some piece of code, please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data have 6 dimensions. You can't visualize data above 2 dimension in a straight forward manner, you need to use PCA or TSNE to visualize them.

Comment: What did you try? Also try posting your answer as it will help some one else :)

Comment: I used PCA to reduce the 6 dimension to 2 , yes I will post it :)

Answer (score 2):

```
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

pca = PCA(n_components=2)

principalComponents = pca.fit_transform(df)

principalDf = pd.DataFrame(data = principalComponents, columns = ['principal component 1', 'principal component 2'])

principalDf.head(5)
```

I used the `PCA` to reduce the `6` dimensions to `2` :
It separates the data perfectly

Output:
[image: Output]